# Is there a way to initialize arrays with mixed chars and "strings"

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I would want to initialize char array during compilation time with least amount of manual work.

Is there a working shorthand format for this

```
char arr[5] = {0x4, 'a', 's', 'd' 'c'};
```

such as

```
char arr[5] = {0x4, "asdc"};
```

Comment: Isn't this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Why would you want to have that `arr`? Shouldn't it be `const` if you want to initialize it at compile time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could integrate the char int the string with escape sequences:

```
char arr[6] = { "\x04asdc"};
```

edit: corrected the wrog length of the array.

Comment: The problem with this is that the string `"\x04asdc"` is *six* characters long. Specifying a to small array size is incorrect.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude please disregard my previous comments, I accidentally ended up on a C page. The nul-terminator is indeed explicitly mandated in C++.

Answer (score 1):

No that's not possible. But you *could* do

```
char arr[] = "\04asdc";
```

The problem with this is that is would not be *exactly* like the original array you show, since it would include the string terminator and therefore have six elements.